# Change y-axis of ts.plot to logarithmic

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

Consider the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

t1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
t2 <- c(4, 5, 4)
t3 <- c(7, 7, 5)
data <- data.frame(t1, t2, t3)

ts.plot(t(data), gpars = list(col = ggplot2::alpha("black", 0.5), ylim = c(0, 10),
xlim = c(0, 10), xlab = "Years", ylab = "Cumulative Numbers"))
```

How can I change the y-axis to a logarithmic scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this doing the trick?

```
ts.plot(t(data), gpars = list(col = ggplot2::alpha("black", 0.5), ylim = c(0.5, 10),
                              xlim = c(1, 10), xlab = "Years", ylab = "Cumulative Numbers"),log = 'y')
```

output:

[image]